# How do I keep databases in sync when internet fails

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, architecture, synchronization

I'm doing some work for a company that has 5 warehouses and a home-grown Inventory Management System which uses a SQL server database in the cloud.  The problem is if one of the warehouses loses internet connectivity all activity ceases.  The IMS is useless without its database.

Is there some way we could run off local copies of the database, which would sync up with the main database when the internet connection is restored?

I've searched the archives and there are a lot of relevant posts but many refer to products or technology which no longer exists. Others assume the reader is smarter than I am!

We can move the database to Azure of AWS if that would be helpful.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: There are many things you could do here and all of them are a massive amount of work. You could use local databases and replication, you could define a custom synchronization process, you could use xml, json, the list goes on and on.

Comment: Another alternative is to invest into a business grade internet connectivity. Also there are various solutions that offer backup connectivity e.g. SD-WAN. This would likely be much cheaper in a short/medium term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with Alex (from the comments).   Get a redundant internet connection at each location...  It is much cheaper than any sort of eventual-consistency solution you would end up with.

If you want to go down the road of a disconnected application, and you are on SQL Server, you really want to look at OCA (Occasionally Connected Applications) and the [Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763484.aspx).  This will require significant rework on the application (as almost all solutions for this problem will).

If the application is of any significant size, you will be looking at hundreds to thousands of hours of effort.  Being home-grown, I would assume it's smaller, so, being conservative, you are looking on the scale of $50K+.

Meanwhile business-class backup internet circuit should run you a couple hundred per month, plus it will make the business more reliable.  Seems like a win-win.